# Javascript collapse DIV on click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm learning javascript, but I'm encountering some problems I need help with. I have a notification box with different groups. I'm wanting it to be possible for only one notification group to be open at a time.

With CSS, i'm having all notification groups collapsed by default. Whenever someone clicks on new group tab, the existing group should collapse and the new tab should open.

CodePin: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/xxgayPa

```js
$('.notification-tab').click(function(e){
  if($(e.currentTarget).parent().hasClass('active')){
    $('.notification-group').removeClass('active');
  }
  else{
    $('.notification-group').removeClass('active');
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().toggleClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.notification-list-item{
  padding: 5px 25px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3}
  .notification-list-item:nth-child(even){background-color: #E3E3E3}

.notification-tab {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%}

.visible {display: block !important}

.profiledrop {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    border-top: 4px solid blue;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}

    .notification-group{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
      overflow: hidden;
      min-height: 65px;}

      .notification-list{
        padding: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 0px;
        max-height: 200px;
        transition: height .15s;}

.active .notification-list {height: 200px;}
.active .notification-tab, .notification-tab:hover {background-color: #5B7042}
.active .label, .notification-tab:hover .label {border: 1px solid white}
.notification-tab:hover {color: white}
.active .label, .active h4 {color: white}

a {color: #5B7042; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold}

      .label{
        float: right;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: $primary-color;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        padding: 0px 7px;
        border-radius: 15px;}
        h4 {margin-left: 10px}
        h4, .label{display: inline-block;}

.item-footer .date{float: right}

.expanded {background-color: purple}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <a href="#" id='launch'>Hi</a>
  <ul class="profiledrop visible">
    <li class="notification-group">
      <div class="notification-tab">
        <h4>Tasks</h4>
        <span class="label">4</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="notification-list">
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Complete an assignment you need to do before the deadline on Monday.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">project3</a></span>
          <span class="date">2m ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="notification-group">
      <div class="notification-tab">
        <h4>Behavior</h4>
        <span class="label">3</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="notification-list">
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Alivia was written up by Mr. Teacher.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Writeup</a></span>
          <span class="date">5s ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Marshall was written up by Mr. Teacher.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Writeup</a></span>
          <span class="date">30m ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Trae was written up by Mr. Teacher.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Writeup</a></span>
          <span class="date">1d ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Kennedy was written up by Mr. Teacher.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Writeup</a></span>
          <span class="date">5d ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="notification-group active">
      <div class="notification-tab">
        <h4>Homework</h4>
        <span class="label">3/3</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="notification-list">
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">History homework added by Patrick.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Assignment</a></span>
          <span class="date">2m ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Math homework added by Patrick.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Assignment</a></span>
          <span class="date">2m ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="notification-list-item">
        <p class="message">Science homework added by Brandi.</p>
        <div class="item-footer">
          <span class="from"><a href="#">View Assignment</a></span>
          <span class="date">2m ago</span>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your codepen appears to be working perfectly (after including jquery into it) -- what is the problem you're having trouble with?

Comment: @DanielBeck When I click "Behavior" - the "Homework" group should close, but it does not open behavior nor does it close homework.

Comment: It's definitely working in Firefox 87.